# Subdomain does not load scripts and styles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, subdomain

Good afternoon,

1- I created a new solution in Visual Studio 2012

2- I created ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. I opted for one project "BASIC" and the Framework 4.5, Razor Engine

3- I created the controller Home

4- I created a View Index.cshtml

The content of Index.cshtml page is only a " Index "

I did nothing, just the main content of a project "BASIC".

Published, see the result:

www.meudominio.com.br -> loads the scripts and styles

imobiliaria589s42d78.meudominio.com.br/ -> NOT load scripts and styles

What should I do to make the subdomain load scripts and styles?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any issues with styles not loading, so I presume this is an issue with caching in your browser. You can force most browsers to reload cached resources by pressing

```
CTRL + F5
```

Comment: Chrome..    PRESS F12 ... Again in the F5 Network tab and will see What NOT Loads . ( 404 Not Found )